# Animate resize and move on group and children of group

Tags: animation, flex4, resize

I have a Spark Group with an image inside and a label control.
`<s:Group><mx:Image source="..."/><s:Label text="Hello!"/></s:Group>`

The image is that of a speech bubble. I want to make the effect of it growing from bottom-right to full size.

How can I do this and make it that resizing the Group will also resize the children?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Group is Sprite, so it has scaleX and scaleY properties. Try setting these, but I don't guarantee anything (UI containers may control their scale coefficients).

Comment: Excellent, idea, thank you. I'll give it a try and let you know.